# issue Importing csv file into magento

Tags: magento, csv, import

So, I am trying to add some products to Imports in the admin page, however, the prices that have a float ending on "0" get truncated by excel. For example, if I have a price of $4.10 it will be truncated into $4.1, and prices on webpage will be displayed as so. 
I thought about creating a vba automation in a macro but there are many different files and it will take too much effort. So, I know I cannot do anything excel-wise. 
Now, magento-wise, I could use $_coreHelper(currency($price); to convert this into the right format, but those anybody knows where can I find these code? Any other ideas? 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: In your description you rule out using Excel and VBA.  You should remove the tags for those.

Comment: Do you have any idea I could apply to solve this with VBA?

Comment: I don't know Magento at all but you can look at exporting the numbers from Excel as a string to preserve the trailing zeros.  However I'm unsure how the csv would have to be set up for Magento. It may not like getting the numbers as strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option for you. I have an `import.php` script that I use to import or update large numbers of products and their attributes. It will let you either update or create a product based on SKU. You would have to check the constants to see if they match your Magento.

```
<?php
include_once("app/Mage.php");
Mage::app();
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));

$counter = 0;

function GetProduct($sku)
{
    global $counter;
    echo $sku;
    $p = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $productId = $p -> getIdBySku($sku);       
    if($productId)
    {
        echo "!";
        $p -> load( $productId );
    }
    else
    {
        $p->setTypeId('simple');
        $p->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH); 
        $p->setStatus(1);
        $p->setTaxClassId(7);
        $p->setWebsiteIDs(array(1)); 
        $p->setStoreIDs(array(1)); 
        $p->setAttributeSetId(4);
        $p->setSku($sku);
    }
    echo "...";
    $counter++;
    echo " ".$counter;
    return $p;
}

function SaveProduct($p)
{
    try
    {
        if (is_array($errors = $p->validate()))
        {
            $strErrors = array();
            foreach($errors as $code=>$error)
            {
                $strErrors[] = ($error === true)? Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Attribute "%s" is invalid.', $code) : $error;
                echo $strErrors[0];
            }
            $this->_fault('data_invalid', implode("\n", $strErrors));
        }
        $p->save();
        echo "\n";
    }
    catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e)
    {
        $this->_fault('data_invalid', $e->getMessage());
    }
}


$product = GetProduct('SKU01'); $product->setData('upc', '013051388461'); SaveProduct($product); unset($product);
$product = GetProduct('SKU02'); $product->setData('special_price', null); $product->setData('special_from_date', null); SaveProduct($product); unset($product);
$product = GetProduct('SKU03'); $product->setData('cardboard_height_cm', 28.5); $product->setData('cardboard_width_cm', 37); SaveProduct($product); unset($product);


?>
```

I often get Excel to create the lines like `$product = GetProduct('SKU03'); $product->setData('cardboard_height_cm', 28.5); $product->setData('cardboard_width_cm', 37); SaveProduct($product); unset($product);` and then just copy and paste into the script. I can edit before running.

This is much faster than importing a CSV and it calls all of the correct observers.

Just run this from a SSH shell.

Comment: I think I am going to try, I don't see how it wouldn't work. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Open Office Calc.

Before entering the values in the price column right click on top of column > Click format cell > Select numbers tab > Select text as shown in the attached image then click ok.

[image: Screenshot]
Now when you enter value like 12.30 it will be as it is in the column.
Also save the file as UTF-8 csv format before importing.

You can verify the created file by opening in notepad++.